# How to call this javascript function from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm putting javascript created controls (http://www.dariancabot.com/projects/jgauge_wip/) on my page.

```
<div class="jgauge" ></div>

$(document).ready(function () {  
    var ctl; 
    ctl = new jGauge();   
    ctl.init();
)}
```

Let's say I need to pass few parameters to `init`. like... `ctl.init(a, b);` from code behind, how can I achieve that? I tried something like this...

```
string script2 = String.Format("init('{0}','{1}')", param1, param2);

this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "initialize control", script2, true);
```

But it's not working. I got:

```
ReferenceError: init is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The init is a method inside jGauge instance. So you must instantiate before you call those mathode. Try bellow:

```
string script2 = String.Format("var ctl; ctl = new jGauge();  ctl.init('{0}','{1}');", param1, param2);
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "initialize control", script2, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

one more way of doing it is to have public variables,

your script would be like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    var ctl; 
    ctl = new jGauge();   
    ctl.init(<%=param1 %>, <%=param2 %>);
)}
```

and in code behind have two public strings

```
public string param1 = string.Empty;
public string param2 = string.Empty;
```

on your `page_load` or any other event, you can set value of these 2 variables normally, like:

```
param1 = "100";
```

rest of the code will work as it is.