# How to call Javascript method from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am a beginner in Javascript.

I have a javascript function

```
Print: function () {
......
}
```

in my "testing.js" file.

now I need to call this "Print" function from a code behind method. How to do...?

I tried all the below but failed every time

http://forums.asp.net/t/1785410.aspx?how+to+call+javascript+function+from+code+behind+cs+file+

[How to call this javascript function from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218631/how-to-call-this-javascript-function-from-code-behind)

and many many..... but didnot get a solution..Any help me to come out from this?

I was working for a day in this and all in vain.

Comment: Is the 'mvc' tag referring to ASP.NET MVC? If it is, then there's no real notion of 'code behind' in ASP.NET MVC...

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek: HI, yes ASP.NET MVC, I would like to have a method name print and in that method i would like to call this JS "Print" function

Comment: You don't call javascript functions directly from server code, it's completely separate domains. The javascript page doesn't even exist yet unless the server code is invoked from Ajax.

Comment: It may be helpful to get a better picture of what you are trying to accomplish.  When you say "code behind", are you wanting the server to tell the browser to print? Or are you wanting a button on your page to call the print function? Or something else?

Comment: your question suffers from the XY problem.  You should ask how to solve your problem, rather than ask why your solution doesn't work. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asp.net mvc and asp.net win-forms are different technologies.
in mvc you do not have a code behind, there is a better isolation between server and client side.
there for there are some options depend on you'r status :

1)if the trigger happens on client you can bind this trigger to a js or jquery function

jquery Example:

```
$('#IDOFButton').bind('click',function(){
   //call print function
   print();
});
```

2)if the trigger happens on server you can send back a js in a script tag to run immediately as it returns to client

```
public JavaScriptResult Print()
        {
            JavaScriptResult js = new JavaScriptResult();
            js.Script = "alert('hello');";
            return js;
        }
```